# SQL - Unable to exclude data using NOT EXIST

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables joined together and a table `NSR_Details` which holds items to be excluded in the Selection of the 3 tables.

I am able to exclude the details referenced from `NSR_details` but when I search with `LIKE` then it still returns the excluded data. Here is my query:

```
SELECT b.MainID
    ,a.Description
    ,b.ItemID
    ,b.Size
    ,c.Current_SRP
    ,b.Barcode
FROM IMF_SKU AS b
LEFT JOIN IMF_Main AS c ON c.MainID = b.MainID
LEFT JOIN IMF_Extensions AS a ON a.MainID = b.MainID
WHERE (a.Description LIKE 'BBB')
    OR (b.Barcode LIKE 'BBB')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM INV_SKU_NSR_DetailsRepo
        )
```

So in NSR_Details I have AAA and BBB data to exclude, (the others have AAA and BBB details as well CCC, DDD, EEE etc are not in NSR_details. I just want to exclude AAA and BBB when I fill up the conditions of the `WHERE` condition. I am using SSMS as my DBMS if anyone asks.

Comment: The NOT EXISTS sub-query needs a reference to the main query in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Having LEFT JOIN's right side table conditions in the WHERE clause like that, makes the LEFT JOIN execute as a regular INNER JOIN. Move to ON to get true left join behavior.

Comment: http://www.geeksengine.com/database/subquery/exists.php

Comment: Why LIKE without any wildcards?

Comment: you understand it but we don't -- how does the table INV_SKU_NSR_DetailsRepo define what to exclude -- what are the field names, what fields do those have to match to show an exclude -- etc.  We need details.

Comment: @Hogan NSR_DetailsRepo has a field which is holds the same data as Main, SKU and Extensions. I just want to select the details from main, sku and extensions which are not in NSR_details table.

Comment: @Hogan, It does?!? Didn't know that. Regardless of collation? Thanks for the info!

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay are sku and extensions independent?  that is does an item in the main table have to match on both values in the row from NSR to be excluded or either?

Comment: @Hogan SKU and Extensions are dependent to Main using MainID.

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay - the answer you selected as correct directly conflicts with what you said in the comments.

Comment: @Hogan Sorry, it was a misclick. My mouse messed-up.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yeah right - comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment

> NSR_DetailsRepo has a field which is holds the same data as Main, SKU
>   and Extensions. I just want to select the details from main, sku and
>   extensions which are not in NSR_details table.

I believe you want this if the fields are dependent

```
SELECT b.MainID
    ,a.Description
    ,b.ItemID
    ,b.Size
    ,c.Current_SRP
    ,b.Barcode
FROM IMF_SKU AS b
LEFT JOIN IMF_Main AS c ON c.MainID = b.MainID
LEFT JOIN IMF_Extensions AS a ON a.MainID = b.MainID
LEFT JOIN INV_SKU_NSR_DetailsRepo nsr on
         nsr.Description = a.Description and
         nsr.Barcode = b.Barcode
WHERE ((a.Description LIKE 'BBB')
    OR (b.Barcode LIKE 'BBB'))
   AND nsr.Description is null
```

or this if the fields are independent

```
SELECT b.MainID
    ,a.Description
    ,b.ItemID
    ,b.Size
    ,c.Current_SRP
    ,b.Barcode
FROM IMF_SKU AS b
LEFT JOIN IMF_Main AS c ON c.MainID = b.MainID
LEFT JOIN IMF_Extensions AS a ON a.MainID = b.MainID
LEFT JOIN INV_SKU_NSR_DetailsRepo nsr on
         nsr.Description = a.Description or
         nsr.Barcode = b.Barcode
WHERE ((a.Description LIKE 'BBB')
    OR (b.Barcode LIKE 'BBB'))
   AND nsr.Description is null
```

This works because a LEFT JOIN with a check for the joined table being null is the same as a NOT IN construct.